# No "Late Answer" in Low Quality Posts review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I wonder why is there no "Late answer" radio button when you choose *Recommend deletion* in the **Low quality posts** review queue.

It could be useful, because other choices does not really fit with that.

Comment: Late answers showing up in the LQPRQ is a good indicator that the answer is a copy. Don't be afraid to open the "link" in a new window to see if the answer is a copy of a previous answer. If it is a copy, I add comment indicating as such, down-vote, and recommend deletion as "no comment needed".

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Late answer" is not a reason to delete a post. Stack Overflow aims at the long term. As time goes by, old questions receive new answers. Answers that give new ways to solve an issue - for example, because new technology has become available to solve an issue in a more elegant way.

Do not delete an answer simply because it comes in long after the question was asked. Delete it if, for some reason, it is not a proper answer. (E.g. question posted as answer, spam answer, "did you find the solution?", etc).

Comment: Ok I see, but in case of duplicate answer? Imagine in 1 year, someone refactor your answer and post it, how should I consider it?

Comment: A new version to an old answer is OK. If the new answer is based on an old answer, the answerer _should_ give credit ("Based upon Zooly's answer [here] ..."). If it is a blatant copy-paste of another answer, then flag for moderator attention. Improving someone else's solution is fine; plagiarism is not.

Comment: Ok so nothing to do in the review queue about low quality. Thanks for clearing up my mind!

Comment: @S.L.Barth In my experience most late answers in the LQPRQ are low effort, redundant answers that add nothing new, and some are blatant copy-and-paste answers, but few actually improve existing answers.